# How to add items with subitems to system context menu using C#

Tags: c#, contextmenu, right-click

I want to add some new items (with subitems) of my software to context menu like this

[image]

So I looked in the registry and found this:

[image]

And I guess that the software "Google Drive" had created some owner classes (or service) to add command to its context menu, and the string {BB02B294-8425-42E5-983F-41A1FA970CD6} is the presentation of this service (or classes), like the Windows SendTo Service (Right click -> Send To)

[image]

But how to do that?

Comment: AFAIK the way to do this is with [shell extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

First of all the most important thing,**there is no way to create nested context menus without context menu handlers**.A context menu handler is nothing but a registered [COM Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) on the users computer.A COM Server exists in the form of a dynamic link library.To explain it better,let me take an example from your first image;The menu entry named **Google Drive** is a COM Server and entries **Copy to Folder** and **Move to Folder** are simple shortcut entries in the registry.Making shortcut entries with specific commands is relatively easy.
To make a shortcut at the desktop context menu for example to **Launch Notepad** ,locate the following registry key in registry editor,**[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell]**,create a new key in it,name it **Launch Notepad**,in its default value add this,**Execute Notepad**.Now create a new key under **Launch Notepad** and name it **command** and add this to its default value **notepad.exe**.That's it,now right click on your desktop you will notice a new entry named **Execute Notepad**,clicking it will open Notepad.So that was the method to create a simple shortcut entry,please note that these shortcut entries cannot be nested means you cannot add any entry under **Execute Notepad** entry.

Now if you want to learn how to get started in making shell extensions,have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1490/Creating-a-shell-extension-with-C).
Hope this would have helped you.